# Amazon RDS Replication

Tags: mysql-replication, amazon-rds

I'm having an issue with working with Amazon RDS in itself, is there a way through RDS to create a seperate RDS instance and have RDS Server 1 replciate to RDS Server 2?

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this within RDS, it's so much easier if I run the MySQL instance on my own infra.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Googling "RDS replication" brings up all sorts of results. Are they not sufficient?

Comment: Yea most lead down avenues of setting up a Multi AZ on the same instance, so essentially.. you can click "Multi AZ" then it will create the same instance and it will replicate for you. 

I need to be able to create a completely different server and setup the replication manually.

Comment: It'd probably help people answer your question if you mentioned the reasons something like multi-AZ or a read replica aren't sufficient. They do have http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_start_replication.html available for your use if you want to do it fully custom.

Answer (score 0):

RDS will handle replication issue itself that's why AWS made RDS. You focus on your work while AWS takes care of all these stuff (replication, backup, failover etc.) 
Create read replica of your RDS instance. Read replica is considered as slave while your RDS instance which is your master is called as Primary.

If you want to set up slave externally below commands would be useful.
All commands to be fired on slave. To reset current master,

```
CALL mysql.rds_reset_external_master;
```

```
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('IP/Domain of your maser server', 'MySQL port', 'replication user', 'password', 'mysql bin changelog file', 'MySQL master position, 0);
```

e.g.

```
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('mymasterserver.mydomain.com', 3306, 'repl_user', 'password', 'mysql-bin-changelog.000031', 107, 0);
```

Command to start replication after changing master,

```
CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
```

Or stop replication command if you need in case,

```
CALL mysql.rds_stop_replication;
```

Comment: Mahadev, adding information on how to create a read replica would make your answer much more useful - screenshots especially. A link to documentation would also improve it.

Comment: The issue with a read replica is it's an identical source that seemingly from the UI of Amazon, it's a replica of your current server specs too. Ideally a second server could have alternative specs and be built independent with the ability to replicate.

Comment: @chris-favaloro, I've added some RDS commands, hope it'll help

Comment: @ChrisFavaloro You can pick the instance size for a read replica, so the steps aren't fixed/identical to the source. http://imgur.com/6FBO4Pf